# Get a line instead of "Notes" when using endnotes

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

I'm using the following code to generate an endnote section (instead of having footnotes pop up on every page they are referred to on.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{endnotes} 
\let\footnote\endnote
\def\footnotetext{\endnotetext[\number\numexpr\value{endnote}+1]}
\let\footnotemark\endnotemark 
\begin{document} 
\footnote{This is a footnote} 
\theendnotes 
\end{document}
```

However, instead of the endnotes having the title "Notes", I would like there to only be a line above the text, just like with standard footnotes. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The header of the endnotes are saved in the the command `\enoteheading`. Here the original definition.

```
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
```

To setup the rule you can use:

```
\def\enoteheading{\par\kern2\baselineskip%
                  \footnoterule%
                  \kern1\baselineskip}
```

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{endnotes,showframe} 
\let\footnote\endnote
\def\footnotetext{\endnotetext[\number\numexpr\value{endnote}+1]}
\let\footnotemark\endnotemark 

\def\enoteheading{\par\kern2\baselineskip%
                  \footnoterule%
                  \kern1\baselineskip}

\begin{document} 
\footnote{This is a footnote} 
\theendnotes 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for using `\footnoterule`.

Comment: The two `\noindent` aren't necessary, but you may want to say `\kern2\baselineskip` or any other spacing you like before `\footnoterule` (which issues `\hrule` and doesn't use `\rule`, so horizontal mode is never started). The `\par` after `\footnoterule` should be omitted.